# Visual Studio Code (VSCODE) no longer can launch electron debug?

Tags: electron

- VSCode Version: 1.12.2
- OS Version: Windows 10
- Electron Version: 1.7

**Steps to Reproduce:**

I did an NPM update for electron, and a few other modules, and the Debug Launch of Electron stopped working. However, I can still manually start Electron from the command prompt, and it seems that the same command is what VSCODE is doing.

I.e. this works:

```
> d:\wwwroot\librarian2017\dashboard/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd --debug-brk=24964 --nolazy main.js
```

But I get the message (below) when I run launch.json, and the blue status bar at the bottom of the VSCODE window turns orange for a second and then goes back to blue. No indication of what crashed. But nothing pops up.

```
Debugging with legacy protocol because a runtime executable is set.
d:\wwwroot\librarian2017\dashboard/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd --debug-brk=24964 --nolazy main.js
```

**Launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "DashBoard",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/main.js",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd",
            "env": {},
            "sourceMaps": true
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a bug in VSCODE. I rolled electron back to 1.6.7 and it works again. I filed an issue on [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26693).